# Reusing a List View in iOS using MVVM

Tags: ios, mvvm, code-reuse, reusability

Is it possible to use the same tableview and cells to display a list of contacts (in module a) and list of secondary contacts (module b) in iOS if I use MVVM pattern? If yes, should i place my views in a separate folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the point with MVVM (are you using REACTIVECOCOA?) and subfolders (having a clean project structure is always useful!) here, but as long as you just want to reuse a table view and it's cells/controller, I would use a embed segue.

From my point of view, the MVVM 'magic' should then happen in the table view itself but is not related to the overall table view reuse.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you as I am new to both MVVM and iOS! I read about reuse a view across modules in MVVM and hence wondering if I really can reuse the list or table view i have created in module a for module b?

Comment: Are you developing native iOS in Xcode or something like Xamarin? What do you define as "module"? are both "modules" in the same storyboard? If yes, you and embed segue to embed the same table and cells in multiple views.

Comment: I am using iOS in Xcode, not xamarin. And modules here I meant like two different pieces of code say, module a contains list of primary contacts and its business logic etc and module b contains secondary contacts and both are independent!

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use a protocol/or base class for the view model so that I can have different view models and use only one tableview controller.